# How can I convert a byte array into a double and back?

Tags: java, double, arrays

For converting a byte array to a double I found this:

```
//convert 8 byte array to double
int start=0;//???
int i = 0;
    int len = 8;
    int cnt = 0;
    byte[] tmp = new byte[len];
    for (i = start; i < (start + len); i++) {
        tmp[cnt] = arr[i];
        //System.out.println(java.lang.Byte.toString(arr[i]) + " " + i);
        cnt++;
    }
    long accum = 0;
    i = 0;
    for ( int shiftBy = 0; shiftBy < 64; shiftBy += 8 ) {
        accum |= ( (long)( tmp[i] & 0xff ) ) << shiftBy;
        i++;
    }

        return Double.longBitsToDouble(accum);
```

But I could not find anything which would convert a double into a byte array.

Comment: How many bytes would you like?  It would be possible, technically, to make an array of bytes that each hold only one bit of information, for example.

Comment: Pops: I think it's fair to imply that Octavian wants only the number of bytes necessary to store a complete representation of a double i.e. matching the internal double representation. In Java, this can be calculated with (int)(Double.Size/Byte.Size) .

Answer (score 120):

Or even simpler,

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public static byte[] toByteArray(double value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
    return bytes;
}

public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Comment: Would be great to know how this compares to a hand-written conversion for performance.

Comment: `return ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8]).putDouble(value).array()` turns the first method into another one-liner

Comment: @cubiclettuce Sadly, `array()` is not required to return anything as the backing structure does not need to be a `byte[]`. That is, it may throw either `UnsupportedOperationException` or `ReadOnlyBufferException` in that order.

Comment: `ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[8])` does the trick. From the Java docs of ByteBuffer.wrap: "The new buffer will be backed by the given byte array"

Answer (score 13):

```
long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(myDouble);
```

Comment: I looked at your question - this isn't a complete answer - however, the same approach as above can be used in reverse if you really want a byte[].

Answer (score 11):

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(double d) {
    long l = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d);
    return new byte[] {
        (byte)((l >> 56) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 48) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 40) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 32) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 24) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 16) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 8) & 0xff),
        (byte)((l >> 0) & 0xff),
    };
}
```

Comment: This is an incomplete answer - and you will find that the problem is in the other half; reconstituting the double is not just a matter of pushing (int)b[0] << 56 | (int)b[1] << 48 | (int)b[2] << 40 (...) through Double.longBitsToDouble(). The ByteBuffer solutions are by far more elegant and headache-free.

Comment: Maybe so, but are not possible from Java ME. This is a working solution. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 10):

The functionality is implemented in the API already. Wrap the byte array in a `ByteBuffer` and use `ByteBuffer.putLong` and `ByteBuffer.getLong`:

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        long[] longArray = { 1234, 2345, 3456 };

        // Longs to bytes
        byte[] bytes = new byte[longArray.length * 8];
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        for (long l : longArray)
            buf.putLong(l);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));

        // Bytes to longs
        ByteBuffer buf2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        long[] longs = new long[bytes.length / 8];
        for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++)
            longs[i] = buf2.getLong(i*8);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(longs));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, -46, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, -128]
[1234, 2345, 3456]
```

Comment: Combine this with `Double.longBitsToDouble` and the inverse and the answer is complete (glowcoder's answer).

Comment: I don't get it, why would I want to go via bits, when going from/to Double and Byte?

Comment: You can blast the entire array to the buffer with `buf.asLongBuffer().put(longArray);`

Answer (score 8):

```
public static final short byteArrayToShort(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getShort();
}

public static final int byteArrayToInt(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
}

public static final float byteArrayToFloat(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getFloat();
}

public static double byteArrayToDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}

public static final long byteArrayToLong(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getLong();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into problems with upper and lower of the double, this seems to be the only code I have seen that corrects for that. I hope it assists others searching for answers in this area. if you do go for some other code, make sure you test the full range of values, you should write a loop that converts to and from for all values and assert them to be sure.

```
// byte2Double method - extracts doubles from byte array
// source: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/bytetoDouble.htm
  public static final double[] byte2Double(byte[] inData, boolean byteSwap) {
    int j = 0, upper, lower;
    int length = inData.length / 8;
    double[] outData = new double[length];
    if (!byteSwap)
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        j = i * 8;
        upper = (((inData[j] & 0xff) << 24)
            + ((inData[j + 1] & 0xff) << 16)
            + ((inData[j + 2] & 0xff) << 8) + ((inData[j + 3] & 0xff) << 0));
        lower = (((inData[j + 4] & 0xff) << 24)
            + ((inData[j + 5] & 0xff) << 16)
            + ((inData[j + 6] & 0xff) << 8) + ((inData[j + 7] & 0xff) << 0));
        outData[i] = Double.longBitsToDouble((((long) upper) << 32)
            + (lower & 0xffffffffl));
      }
    else
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        j = i * 8;
        upper = (((inData[j + 7] & 0xff) << 24)
            + ((inData[j + 6] & 0xff) << 16)
            + ((inData[j + 5] & 0xff) << 8) + ((inData[j + 4] & 0xff) << 0));
        lower = (((inData[j + 3] & 0xff) << 24)
            + ((inData[j + 2] & 0xff) << 16)
            + ((inData[j + 1] & 0xff) << 8) + ((inData[j] & 0xff) << 0));
        outData[i] = Double.longBitsToDouble((((long) upper) << 32)
            + (lower & 0xffffffffl));
      }

    return outData;
  }
```