# Sending game updates using byte[] and converting to numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This might be a duplicate of [Convert byte array to numbers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361086/convert-byte-array-to-numbers-in-javascript) but the best answer there is quite old (maybe there is something new?) and I would also like to approach this in an open ended manner and ask a broader question regarding if there is a better way to send data in a performant way instead of what I am trying to do.

I am currently working on making a real time game using webrtc run by a C# server.

For updating the client I am currently playing around with this code converting numbers to a `byte[]` which I can then send to the client (to minimize the data, this turns into 50 bytes). This is important as I'll be sending several updates per second.

```
public static byte[] UserLocationToByte(long userId, double x, double y, double r, double dx, double dy)
{
    var msg = new List<byte[]>
    {
        BitConverter.GetBytes((short)DataMessageType.Location),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(userId),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(x),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(y),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(r),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(dx),
        BitConverter.GetBytes(dy)
    };

    var t = msg.SelectMany(a => a).ToArray();
    return t;
}
```

In C# I could convert this back to the number values using.

```
// convert it back.
var rtype = (DataMessageType)BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 0);
var ruserId = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 2);
var rx = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 2 + 8);
var ry = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 2 + 8 + 8);
var rr = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 2 + 8 + 8 + 8);
var rdx = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 2 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8);
var rdy = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 2 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 + 8);
```

Searching around I found no simple way to do this in javascript/typescript.

I could just send strings with | separators and parse those in javascript, but that would increase the amount of data by quite alot.

Any suggestions as to how to either parse a byte[] in javascript or another way to approach this problem all together?

I have no problem just supporting firefox and chrome.

Comment: How exactly are you getting the data client side, ie what format (string, blob, etc)? Javascript itself has Typed Arrays like Int8Array which would be a byte array and the values are already numbers.

Comment: You might want to look into DataView's, one problem you might have is that Javascript doesn't support 64bit integers..  You could maybe get around this using a third party lib for this,.  But does your userID have to be 64bit?

Comment: @PatrickEvans javascript is getting an int8Array, but parsing that back seems quite obtuse (looking at the other thread linked). Im worried that when javascript is receiving 50+ of these per second that might not be so great.

Comment: @Keith No I it does not, I'm quite sure that Ill have other problems before I reach Int32.MaxValue. I'll change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming an unsigned int, is big enough for userid's.

You could use a DataView,

Below is an example, it will then return an ArrayBuffer that you can use to send the data etc.

The `true` at the end of each set is so that little endian is used, this should then be compatible with C# on windows.

If your on Chrome you can view what's in the ArrayBuffer and confirm if it looks correct..

```js
const msgTypeLocation = 1;


function UserLocationToByte(userId, x, y, r,  dx, dy)
{
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(46);
  const dv = new DataView(buffer);
  let o = 0;
  dv.setInt16(0, msgTypeLocation, true); o += 2;
  dv.setUint32(o, userId, true); o += 4;
  dv.setFloat64(o, x, true); o += 8;
  dv.setFloat64(o, y, true); o += 8;
  dv.setFloat64(o, r, true); o += 8;
  dv.setFloat64(o, dx, true); o += 8;
  dv.setFloat64(o, dy, true); o += 8;
  return buffer;
}


const data = UserLocationToByte(10, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 10.0, 12.0);
console.log(data);
```

```html
Look in Chrome Console, etc. to see the bytes.
```

Comment: Probably should also include examples of the `get*` versions of the methods since they are likely to want to use those on the client side in order to read the values back.