# Best and efficient way to convert double value into a byte array in Java

Tags: java, performance

I'm working on a low latency system and need a solution to convert a double number to byte array but with precision for decimal numbers. I need to consider there should be less object creation within the solution. Also, I'm getting value as double.

My current implementation is somewhat like

```
int offset = 0;
double d = 1211.11;
long integerPart = (long) d;
byte[] b = new byte[16];

offset += addToByteArray(integerPart, b, offset); 
//implementation to add each digit to byte array, returns new offset

int lengthDecimal = 16 - offset;
if(lengthDecimal > 0)
b[offset++] = '.';
long tmp = 1;

for(int i=0; i<lengthDecimal; i++){
 tmp = tmp * 10;
 int digit = (int)(((long) (d * tmp)) % 10);
 b[offset++] = (byte) ('0' + digit);
}
```

Then the byte array is manipulated to trim later zeros and '.' if required.

The problem is if I check the byte array, I don't find the exact digits. Since, I'm using double, the precision of decimal point is lost while working.

I've searched and found everywhere to use BigDecimal. The use of BigDecimal seems to work fine but I'm worried about the performance and number of objects created as this part of the code is hit frequently.

I've also tried to work with String like this

```
String doubleNumber = Double.toString(d);
long fractionalPart = 0;

offset += addToByteArray(integerPart, b, offset); 
if(doubleNumber.substring(doubleNumber.indexOf(".")).length() > 0) {
  fractionalPart = Long.valueOf(doubleNumber.substring(doubleNumber.indexOf(".") + 1));
  b[offset++] = '.';
  offset += addToByteArray(fractionalPart, b, offset);
}
```

Please suggest me the best approach for the purpose.

Comment: "I'm worried about the performance .." <-- Don't be. Either 1) Be lazy/uninformed and don't worry; or 2) *Profile the application* and know if there is an issue (or not).

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a `byte` and a `char`?  It looks to me like you simply want to format a floating-point number into a String, and there are a half-dozen different ways to do that.

Comment: Do you want raw bytes, or text?

Comment: @msandiford raw bytes to be sent on wire.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a byte array into a double and back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back) (and many others)

Comment: "Raw bytes" implies sending the binary vs character representation of the number.  Those are two entirely different things.  Maybe you should state your *requirement* vs your assumed implementation.

Comment: @HotLicks it will be character(ASCII) representation of the numbers. I'm bit confused here on binary vs character

Comment: If it's to be character representation then you don't want `byte`, you want `char` or `String`.  It may be that the final data needs to be converted to `byte` to be transmitted, but that's a separate step, performed on the bulk data, and usually done by the network API code.  (And if you're "sending on a wire" then the performance of the data conversion is inconsequential in comparison -- just use a built-in formatter.)

Answer (score 10):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(yourDouble);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want low latency, then the important thing is to avoid heap memory allocations (which cause GC pauses at some unspecified later point).

So I'm assuming that:

- You have allocated your byte array in advance
- You want to put a double in your byte array without doing any intermediate allocations

The trick is to use `doubleToLongBits`:

```
long v = Double.doubleToLongBits(myDouble);
```

Then write the `long` into the correct position in your byte array (presumably using 8  consecutive bytes). You might as well just do this the brute force way:

```
data[pos+7] = (byte)(v);
data[pos+6] = (byte)(v>>>8);
data[pos+5] = (byte)(v>>>16);
data[pos+4] = (byte)(v>>>24);
data[pos+3] = (byte)(v>>>32);
data[pos+2] = (byte)(v>>>40);
data[pos+1] = (byte)(v>>>48);
data[pos]   = (byte)(v>>>56);
```

Note we are using primitives at every point, so there are no memory allocations throughout this process.

Comment: Except that he now says that he wants a character representation.

Comment: Well a character array certainly won't be the most efficient.....

Answer (score -2):

If you want a double formatted into an ASCII (character) string then String.format is probably the simplest approach that gives you control over the format:

```
String result = String.formatter("%5.3f", theDoubleValue);
```

Comment: And then `byte[] bytes = result.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`.

Comment: @msandiford - Except I'd bet you real money that he doesn't really want `byte` data.

Comment: Actually I want an array of bytes. The array contains the byte value of ascii encoded characters. 

eg; the value is 1234
byte[0] = 31
byte[2] = 32
byte[3] = 33
byte[4] = 34

Comment: @darkapple -- WHY do you want an array of bytes?  What are you going to do with the data?