# double to long without conversion in Java

Tags: java, casting, double, long-integer

I need to turn double into long preserving its binary structure, not number value. Just change type, but leave binary value as it is. Is there a native way to do it?

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToRawLongBits%28double%29) with to doubleToLongBits and doubleToLongRawBits. *Javadoc is your friend.*