# Properly reading 4 bytes in -Hex- NSData form into its proper data type (float or int) in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, hex, nsdata

I will try to be as explicit as possible I appreciate all the help in advance!.

I am trying to write an iOS 8 app that uses the CoreBluetooth framework for Swift. I know how to initiate and obtain the values and subscribe to the values I want from the Bluetooth BLE peripherals in Swift, that will not be an issue. I do however need help in understanding and properly translating the values I'm receiving into the values that I can properly use.

I am using a BLE peripheral to send analog data in a Float form. Checking for the characteristics.value.length property I know I receive 4 bytes in Hexadecimal form. Also using the LightBlue app, I also have understood that the format the information is being received is a 4-byte little endian float.

An example of the values that I receive from the output window are:

- <00404f44>
- <00404f44>
- <00804e44>
- <00404e44>
- <00c04d44>
- <00404d44>
- <00804c44>
- <00c04c44>
- <00404c44>

The analog values being sent are from a potentiometer ranging from 0 - 1023, and while a 0x0000803F hex gives me a value of 1.0000 and a 0x00C07F44 hex gives me a value of 1023.0000 (From the LightBlue app) I don't really know how to convert these values from Hex into Floats?

I found a sample app that does this in Objective-C, however I'm new to swift and would like to do this app in swift-only. The Example app code that does this is the following:

```
float dataFloat(NSData *data)
{
    uint8_t *p = (uint8_t*)[data bytes];
    NSUInteger len = [data length];
    return (sizeof(float) <= len ? *(float*)p : 0);

}
```

Which is called by:

```
float analog = dataFloat(data);
```

I don't want to translate this information to a string however, because later I will try to do some playing around with the values (Once they have been translated into values I know and am comfortable with) But for now I would like my output window to display instead of a 0x00C07F44 hex for example, a 1023...

I would also like to thank you all for taking the time to read my question, and while it may seem similar to other people's... I have tried their solutions and they don't seem to fit on mine, I admit I am quite new to this so I apologize and hope for your consideration.

Please let me know if there's any other information I can provide that I may have missed!

Sincerely,

Maverik0106

Comment: Take a look at `fromByteArray` in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953591/how-to-convert-a-double-into-a-byte-array-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a while of research and community polling, I have found the answer from one of the community members at: http://forum.rfduino.com/index.php?topic=727.15#msg3393 So credit goes to him.

The code that properly translates the data into a UInt32 and then into a float is this:

```
  var test:UInt32 = 0

  data.getBytes(&test, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
  var floatVal:Float = unsafeBitCast(reversed, Float.self)
  println(floatVal)
```

Assuming you have your 'data' variable as an NSData.

However if you have a similar problem but you need to flip the bytes before converting them into floats the code changes to this:

```
  var test:UInt32 = 0          
  data.getBytes(&test, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
  var reversed = test.byteSwapped
  var floatVal:Float = unsafeBitCast(reversed, Float.self)
  println(floatVal)
```

This solution accounts for both Endianness. Big thanks to Bill for providing this solution

An even smaller/better solution would be:

```
  var floatVal:Float = 0.0;
  data.getBytes(&floatVal, length:sizeof(Float))
  println(floatVal)
```

This one would does not flip bits tho, so if it doesn't need to swap bytes then this would be the safer/better route.