# UInt8[4] to Int in swift

Tags: swift, int, uint

I use following function to implement Int to UInt8[4] converter:

```
    func toByteArray(var value: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    var msgLength = [UInt8](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0)

    for i in 0...3 {
        msgLength[i] = UInt8(0x0000FF & value >> Int((3 - i) * 8))
    }
    return msgLength
    }
```

How to implement Int to UInt8[4]?

Comment: You could refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953591/how-to-convert-a-double-into-a-byte-array-in-swift) SO link

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[How to convert a type to/from a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954091/1630618)

```
func toByteArray( value: Int) -> [UInt8] {
    var msgLength = [UInt8](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0)

    for i in 0...3 {
        msgLength[i] = UInt8(0x0000FF & value >> Int((3 - i) * 8))
    }
    return msgLength
}

// call your function to generate the byte array.  Reverse the order
// since fromByteArray wants them in the reverse (little endian) order    
let b = Array(toByteArray(1234567890).reverse())

func fromByteArray<T>(value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
    return value.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        return UnsafePointer<T>($0.baseAddress).memory
    }
}

let i = fromByteArray(b, Int32.self)
print(i) // 1234567890
```