# fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer

Tags: ios, swift

For **iPhone5 (10.2) simulator** this function:

```
static func fromByteArray<T>(_ value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
        return value.withUnsafeBytes {
            $0.baseAddress!.load(as: T.self)
        }
    }
```

crashes at `$0.baseAddress!.load(as: T.self)` with this error:

> fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer

Does somebody know the solution?

I'm using this code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26954091/1979882

**EDIT**
it works for iPhone5s but not iPhone5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, it crashes as you described. The solution is to use this function to convert byte array to desired type:

```
func fromByteArray<T>(_ value: [UInt8], _: T.Type) -> T {
        return value.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
            $0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: 1) {
                $0.pointee
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my results from testing (red crashes the iPhone 5 simulator for unknown reason):
[image]