# Swift: best way to send large arrays of numbers ([Double]) over HTTP

Tags: ios, json, swift, http

I thought I'd ask after hours of inconclusive research and tests:

### Introduction

I'm trying to send very large arrays of `Double`s from an app to a server, naturally, I want to compress this as much as possible.
Specifically, these array contain `CMDeviceMotion` components (acceleration, x, y, z, gyroscope, etc...), but this question should apply to any large array of numbers (over 100K or a million values)

### What I've tried and found by researching options

Say I have a large array of `Double` (There are many others) :

`var CMX = CM.map({$0.userAcceleration.x})`

here, `CMX` is of type `[Double]` and `CM` is `[CMDeviceMotion]`

I've tried making `POST` requests to my server by sending  `CMX` in different ways, then calculating the total size after I receive it on the server :

1. First, as a single comma separated string : 

   `{"AX":"-0.0441827848553658,-0.103976868093014,-0.117475733160973,-0.206566318869591,-0.266509801149368,-0.282151937484741,-0.260240525007248,-0.266505032777786,-0.315020948648453,-0.305839896202087,0.0255246963351965,0.0783950537443161,0.0749507397413254,0.0760494321584702,-0.0101579604670405,0.106710642576218,0.131824940443039,0.0630970001220703,0.21177926659584,0.27022996544838,0.222621202468872,0.234281644225121,0.288497060537338,0.176655143499374,0.193904414772987,0.169417425990105,0.150193274021149,0.00871349219232798,-0.0270088445395231,-0.0 ....`

Size 153 Kb.

It makes sense that this is larger than sending as binary data, since a single number here is 64 bits (8 bytes), and becomes 17 bytes long (one byte per character) +1 = 18 (added a character for the comma).

With this reasoning, sending the array as binary data should be smaller.

2. Base 64 encoding

Here, I convert the array to a `Data` object using `NSKeyedArchiver` and base 64 encode the data before sending it :

`["AX":NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:CM.map({$0.userAcceleration.x})).base64EncodedString()]`

This made the file size 206 Kb

3. Sending the data as a JSON array

By just sending :

`["AX": CM.map({$0.userAcceleration.x})]`

It turned out that this array of numbers was practically converted to a comma separated string, the size ended up being the same as in trial 1 (160Kb)

4. Sending as `Data` without base 64 encoding

Doing this:

`["AX":NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:CM.map({$0.userAcceleration.x}))`

made the application crash at runtime, so I can't send a `Data` object as a value in a JSON

### Question

How can I send these array in a more condensed way in a  JSON object ?

Note that I already have downsampling in mind, and using 32 bit floats to reduce the size.

Comment: You could try and zip the data string, and send it base64 encoded, or try to get the binary representation of the Double (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953591/how-to-convert-a-double-into-a-byte-array-in-swift  ) and send it base64 encoded

Comment: Any compression methods would request to know the potential patterns of your data. e.g. data range, does order matter, fixed decimal number, etc.

Comment: You may look at [Protocol Buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers), there's even [Apple's implementation for Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way would be to do this:

```
let data: Data = CMX.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in
    return Data(buffer: pointer)
}
```

And you have binary buffer with all your Doubles/Floats combined.

But because HTTP is text-based protocol you will have to convert this `data` to base64 string:

```
let base64String = data.base64EncodedString()
```

And this `base64String` should be passed for `AX` parameter of your `POST`*(?)* `HTTP` request.

**EDIT**:

To convert it back you may use code like this:

```
extension Array {
    init?(data: Data) {
        // This check should be more complex, but here we just check if total byte count divides to one element size in bytes
        guard data.count % MemoryLayout<Element>.size == 0 else { return nil }

        let elementCount = data.count / MemoryLayout<Element>.size
        let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>.allocate(capacity: elementCount)
        data.copyBytes(to: buffer)

        self = buffer.map({$0})
        buffer.deallocate()
    }

   // Wrapped here code above
    var data: Data {
        return self.withUnsafeBufferPointer { pointer in
            return Data(buffer: pointer)
        }
    }
}

let converted: [Double]? = Array(data: CMX.data) // converted now should be equal to CMX
```

Comment: Brilliant answer ! this brought the file size down to 82 Kb (from 153) for 64 bit doubles and 40 Kb for 32 bit Floats

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for your help. How do I turn the data back to an array ?

Comment: @kmn, added to the answer