# byte[] to double representation

Tags: java, casting, double, arrays

I have some troubles with a wav reading.
I have to read a wav file sample per sample.

To do this, I first try to print my 128 first samples to see if I have good values (I know what they are). To do that :

```
private int bytesToInt(byte[] fenetre, int debut, int nbByte) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbByte; i++) {
        res <<= 8;
        res += fenetre[debut + i];
    }
    return res;
}

public void afficherPremiereFenetre() throws IOException {
    int tailleFenetre = 128;
    int nbBytePerSample = au.getFormat().getFrameSize();
    int nbBytePerFrame = tailleFenetre * nbBytePerSample;
    byte[] fenetre = new byte[nbBytePerFrame];
    au.read(fenetre, 0, nbBytePerFrame);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbBytePerFrame; i += nbBytePerSample) {
        System.out
                .println((double) bytesToInt(fenetre, i, nbBytePerSample));
    }
}
```

So my question is : how to really translate my byte[] frame to double ?

Comment: Converting byte[] to double[]:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with `java.nio.ByteBuffer`

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(fenetre).getDouble();
```

> Given a direct byte buffer, the Java virtual machine will make a best
>   effort to perform native I/O operations directly upon it. That is, it
>   will attempt to avoid copying the buffer's content to (or from) an
>   intermediate buffer before (or after) each invocation of one of the
>   underlying operating system's native I/O operations.