# Java equivalent of struct.unpack('d', s.decode('hex'))[0]

Tags: java, python, binaryfiles

I am reading a file which is stored binaries. 
In python I can decode the file easily

```
>>> s = '0000000000A0A240'
>>> s.decode('hex')
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\xa2@'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('d', s.decode('hex'))[0]
2384.0
```

Now I want to do the same decoding in Java, do we have anything similar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Comment: Are you reading double from bytes? Then this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074533/2288384 - easy way using `ByteBuffer.wrap(...).getXXX()`

Comment: @VladimirL. None of the getter return what I want

Comment: and what do you want? sorry, I'm not so good in Python and its std library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since those bytes are in Little-Endian order, being C code on an Intel processor, use `ByteBuffer` to help flip the bytes:

```
String s = "0000000000A0A240";
double d = ByteBuffer.allocate(8)
                     .putLong(Long.parseUnsignedLong(s, 16))
                     .flip()
                     .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                     .getDouble();
System.out.println(d); // prints 2384.0
```

Here I'm using `Long.parseUnsignedLong(s, 16)` as a quick way to do the `decode('hex')` for 8 bytes.

---

If data is already a byte array, do this:

```
byte[] b = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0xA2, 0x40 };
double d = ByteBuffer.wrap(b)
                     .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                     .getDouble();
System.out.println(d); // prints 2384.0
```

Imports for the above are:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
```

Comment: nice one, the problem is I don't have it as String I have it as a bye[], something like 
for (byte[] val : redis.getValues()) {....}

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Use an IDE. It would help you with the imports.

Comment: I simplified the creation of bytes from string a bit: `ByteBuffer.wrap(DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("0000000000A0A240"))`, but good catch with `LITTLE_ENDIAN` also got the result `2384.0` after applying order method.

Comment: @VladimirL. Sure it appears simpler, but using a JAXB class for hex parsing just seems sooo .... *Yuck!* .... Besides, `DatatypeConverter` is not available in Java 9 SE by default.

Comment: @Andreas at least it's better than pull the `commons-codec` dependency into a project as most of the ppl do :) And Oracle for some reason decided that `Base64` is the only decoder/encoder that developers need. I knew that `java.xml` is deprecated, but didn't know that `javax.xml.bind` is completely removed from Java 9 JDK (SE).

Comment: @VladimirL. It's not removed, but JAXB is in the `java.xml.bind` module, which is not enabled by default. You need `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to use it, or `--add-modules java.se.ee` since it's imported with the `java.se.ee` module. That why I said "by default".

Comment: Yeah, thanks for clarification! I noticed the module graph picture in [JDK docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html) and also read [Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942951/2288384) in the other answer about Java 9, but "in short" the shortcut with `DatatypeConverter` will be (or is already) useless with Java 9 and no strait replacement, so sad.

Comment: @VladimirL. Yeah, agreed, so sad that Java doesn't come with Hex to `byte[]` and `byte[]` to hex converters. Why is such a simple and common function missing?