# android convert double array to byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, double

First I converted a byte array to a double array to make same math operations (see code below):

```
private double[] bytesToDouble(File file){

    InputStream in = null;
    if (file.isFile()) {
        long size = file.length();
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            return readStreamAsDoubleArray(in, size);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Now I would like to convert it back into a byte array to save it again to a wav file. How do I do that? The problem is that I have a double array and in the answer the use a double value, but not a double array. That`s why the following answer doesn`t help me: [How can I convert a byte array into a double and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back

Comment: Thanks for answering, the problem is that I have a double array and in the answer the use a double value, but not a double array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a byte array into a double and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905556/how-can-i-convert-a-byte-array-into-a-double-and-back)

Comment: According to my previous commentary it explains why this question doen`t help me.

Comment: Show the code of `readStreamAsDoubleArray()`.Show how you convert a byte to a double.

Comment: And show how you want a double to be converted to a byte. Not every double value can be converted to a byte. How do you wanna manage that?